# splitting a variable in a make file

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, split

I have a variable lets say
x=tpm/tpm

in a makefile i want to be able to split x to halves.

in bash this would be something like ${x%/*} and ${x#*/}

but how do i do it in a makefile?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's a pathname (or even if it's not and the separator is always `/`), you can use the `dir` and `notdir` functions.

```
half1 = $(dir $(x))
half2 = $(notdir $(x))
```

Answer (score 16):

For a more general solution (e.g. if there are more than two parts, or if the separator isn't always '/') you can use this approach:

```
y = $(subst /, ,$(x))

half1 = $(word 1, $(y))
half2 = $(word 2, $(y))
```

Comment: @AlexReece, true, it's not *that* general. The next step would be a call to `sed`.

Comment: If the separator is a space then I think it works if you declare a variable containing a space and then use that variable in `subst`.

Comment: `$(subst ...)` and `$(word ...)` are not compatible with POSIX.  These are features that are specific to GNU make.